# How do I update the BASE_URL defined in my gradle through UI?

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog, android-buildconfig

I am currently working on creating an alertdialog box with edittext in it which opens on tap on my login screen , which should allow the capability to update the BASE_URL defined in my gradle.
Say for instance I am currently defining my base_url as follows:

```
 buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://myapp.com/api\"")
```

which upon running the app translated to a buildConfig URL such that in Buildconfig.java it shows as :

```
  public static final String BASE_URL = "https://myapp.com/api";
```

Now my question is ,how do I update this base url on the edit text box i add in the alertdialog on the login screen, such that if i change the edit text text to :

```
https://myapp.com/api2
```

upon clicking save it should save the new entry and apply it to buildconfig file throughout the course of the app. I also want to display a reset button to allow the capability to reset this URL back to the original. Any ideas how to go about it?

am using a similar code for alertdialog as this : https://medium.com/@mujtahidah/custom-dialog-with-edittext-and-button-action-android-fc64ef5eb2b2

Just want to know if there is a way BASE_URL can be updated in the UI dynamically and saved on the fly? Any ideas or examples?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your question itself has the answer.

- Just want to know if there is a way BASE_URL can be updated in the UI dynamically and saved on the fly?
- answer: *No*

Generated `BuildConfig.java` file contains all `static and final` fields.

`public static final String BASE_URL = "https://myapp.com/api";`

In java you can't change the `final` fields.

Suggestion:
On taping of save button in your alert dialog save the updated URL in instance variable(which will be gone on closing the application) or store in `SharedPreferences`(which will be available even after reopening the application). So that you can use the Variable wherever you want in further.

Answer (score 0):

So basically BuildConfig is a generated file, which happens at compile time. So if you want to use a value that you are setting at Runtime, you should probably use something in Memory, or use a shared preferences. You cannot edit a compile-time generated file during runtime.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


prefs.edit().putString("base_url", "your new base url").apply();


String baseUrl = prefs.getString("base_url", BuildConfig.BASE_URL); 
// BuildConfig.BASE_URL being your default value
```

Comment: so in my case how do i go about updating the base_url?

Comment: I have given a sample in my answer now. Let me know if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: this probably shouldn't be `BuildConfig` but a string resource.

Comment: can any of you guys help me with this issue with skeleton loading : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012218/how-do-i-update-my-skeleton-layout-code-such-that-it-doesnt-block-my-viewpager

Comment: also wonder how you can start parsing base url if its returned from a json query